# calling a Spring bean from java class explicitly

Tags: java, spring

I have a file named abc.xml i which the below bean is defined , request you to please advise how can i call this bean in my java class explicitly , i want to call this bean as reference of this bean is there in my class so i want to call this bean from my java class explicitly

below is the spring bean defined in abc.xml

```
<bean id="springJobExecutor" class="com.scheduler.autosys.core.SpringBeanJobExecutor" singleton="false"/>
```

and i want to call this bean from java class explicitly please advise

Comment: Inject the bean into the caller using Spring and it will be able to call it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply how to inject by calling reference attribute please advise as I am new to spring

Comment: You should read the Spring docs.  This is Spring dependency injection 101.  You cannot use Spring without understanding this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean simple injection? You have to create ApplicationContext object and get an instance from it:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("abc.xml");

SpringBeanJobExecutor springJobExecutor =
context.getBean("springJobExecutor", SpringBeanJobExecutor.class);
```

Or if you mean dependency injection using constructor...

```
<bean id="springJobExecutor"
class="com.scheduler.autosys.core.SpringBeanJobExecutor" singleton="false"/>

<bean id="myObject" class="myClass" >
    <constructor-arg index="[argument_index]" ref="springJobExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

or using setter...

```
<bean id="springJobExecutor"
class="com.scheduler.autosys.core.SpringBeanJobExecutor" singleton="false"/>

<bean id="myObject" class="myClass" >
    <property name="[name]" ref="springJobExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

and finally getting the object in main...

```
MyClass myObject = context.getBean("myObject", MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Or just make the object with the dependency a bean under Spring's control and inject in the bean you'd like it to call.